# How to speed up printing line by line to a file in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say I'm printing numbers from two arrays into a file:

```
from numpy import random
number_of_points = 10000
a = random.rand(number_of_points)
b = random.rand(number_of_points)
fh = open('file.txt', 'w')
for i in range(number_of_points):
    for j in range(number_of_points):
        print('%f %f' % (a[i], b[j]), file=fh)
```

I feel this is making lots of calls to the system to print, whereas sending one call containing this information would be faster. Is this correct? If so, how could I do this? Are there faster ways to implement this?

Comment: How slow is it? After testing, have you determined that it is too slow for your purposes? If so, are you sure that the culprit is the repeated `print` calls? Have you tried `print('\n'.join(['%f %f' % (a[i], b[i]) for i in range(number_of_points)]))`?

Comment: In my application, any speed improvement in this segment is desired. Profiling pins `print` as the culprit. How would I do the above for a nested for loop? Edited above to include nested `for` loop.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: That suggestion would create a 100M item `list` of `str` in memory, as well as a `str` with the combined length of all of them as the peak RAM required. That's multiple GB of memory required, more than many systems possess. You don't want to solve this with a solution that doesn't write piecemeal.

Comment: The data is written to a local buffer and flushed to the system cache when the buffer fills. You'll get a minor boost with a larger internal buffer as in `fh = open('file.txt', 'w', 2**24)` which creates a 16 meg buffer. Eventually the system buffer fills and your program slows to your disk I/O speed.

Comment: Say I'm performing this I/O on a `tmpfs` (FYI I'm "gluing" two closed sourced programs which transmit data to each other a whole lot, i.e. one program's modified output is another program's input). Does this buffer occur in the RAM or some other devices cache? It seems if the buffer occurs in the RAM there is a redundancy and I ought to forgo buffers all together.

Comment: @bfletch - it depends on how these apps are written (for instance, do they use DIRECTIO) but generally data goes into the system cache in RAM and is flushed to disk over time. Whether that data is still in RAM when your other program reads it depends on whether other things have used system RAM and invalidated the cache. That in turn depends on how much RAM you have and what other things are running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`print` has a lot of bells and whistles you're not using, and you're using C-style looping with indexing instead of direct iteration, both of which add needless overhead. You might be able to speed it up a bit by limiting the Python level work, pushing it to the C layer.

For example, in this case, you could replace the whole doubly-nested loop structure with:

```
import itertools

# You could use '%f %f\n'.__mod__ as the map function if you like, I just
# find the modern format strings a little nicer
fh.writelines(itertools.starmap('{} {}\n'.format, itertools.product(a, b)))
```

which uses `product` to produce the results of your nested loops and indexing directly, `starmap`+`str.format` to create the lines, and `fh.writelines` to exhaust the generator created by `starmap`, writing all of its outputs directly to the file with a single function call, instead of 100,000,000 calls to to `print`.

Aside from the fixed (unrelated to number of items iterated) setup cost to create the generators and pass the final generator to `fh.writelines`, the actual iteration, formatting and I/O work will take place entirely at the C layer on the CPython reference interpreter, so it should run quite fast.

Comment: Even without itertools (which may not fit OP's real code as well as his example). using `file.write` is a great tip. It'll be perhaps twice as fast at print.

Comment: @tdelaney what performance benefit does `io.TextIOBase.write(s)` and `io.IOBase.writelines(lines)` have in comparison to `print()`? It seems `print()` and `io.TextIOBase.write(s)` both buffer on a line-by-line basis, whereas `io.IOBase.writelines(lines)` buffers to account for all lines? Is this correct?

Comment: @bfletch I don't know why `print` is slower, but its not a question of line buffering. Buffering is decided when the file is opened. A terminal defaults to line buffered, while files and pipes default to block buffered - your print was not line buffered. I increased the file buffer size to 16 Meg  in a test and even though the number of system writes plummeted by a factor of 2000, the overall execution time remained about the same, When I changed to `write`, execution time dipped ~ 40%. So, its a question of `print` being slow, not sytem buffering. Your mileage may vary!

Comment: @ShadowRanger I get `IndexError: tuple index out of range` with this solution.

Comment: @bfletch: Oops, my mistake. Need to use `itertools.starmap`, not plain `map` for `format` call. Fixed. You'd use plain `map` if you used `'%f %f\n'.__mod__` as the mapping function.